# Ajax tiene algún tipo de limitación a la hora de enviar y recibir datos?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Pues esa es mi pregunta, lo digo porque yo utilizo ajax para mostrar unas imagenes llamando unas funciones que permiten hacer la gestión en la base de datos sin necesidad de recargar la pagina. Pero he querido añadir un sistema de rating que FUNCIONA dentro de ajax para luego mostrarlo en el html, pero si añado esa linea de código el ajax deja de funcionar.

No me randomiza las imagenes, ni me devuelve un console.log con el json de todos los datos, en cambio si comento la linea del rating vuelve a funcionar, eso porque pasa ?

Archivo php que ejecuta ajax:

```
<?php
    require_once('./db/conecta_db.php');
    require_once('./lib/funciones.php');

    $idPhoto = $_POST['idPhoto'];
    $urlPath = $_POST['urlPath'];
    
    $row = imgRandom($db,$urlPath);
    $Likes = devolverlikes($db,$row['idPhoto']);
    $Dislikes = devolverdislikes($db,$row['idPhoto']);
    $rating = devolverRating($Likes,$Dislikes);
    $comentarios= construirComentarios($db,$row['idPhoto']);
    $hashtags = construirHashtags($db,$row['idPhoto']);
    
    $mdata= array(
        "idPhoto"=>$row['idPhoto'],
        "title"=>$row['title'],
        "description"=>$row['description'],
        "urlPath"=>$row['urlPath'],
        "comentarios"=>$comentarios,
        "hashtags"=>$hashtags,
        "rating"=>$rating
    );

echo json_encode($mdata);
```

Hay que decir que como la función imgRandom,likes,dislikes,hashtags son funciones que hacen una petición a la base de datos. En cambio la función devolverRating calcula los likes y dislikes para devolver las estrellas que equivalen.

Eso significa que ajax tiene que hacer varias peticiones por lo que se ralentiza a la hora de cargar la información o esta capado ? Hay alguna forma de solucionarlo ? La función funciona perfectamente, no creo que sea por ello.

Edito la pregunta con la función de rating:

```
function devolverRating($likes,$dislikes){
  $r=0;
  if(($likes+$dislikes)>0){
    $r=round($likes/($likes+$dislikes)*5);
  }
  $rating="";
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
      if($i<$r){
          $rating.="<i class='fas fa-star'></i>";
      }else{
        $rating.="<i class='far fa-star'></i>";
      }

    }

  return $rating;
}
```

Pongo las funciones que utilizo en ajax:

```
function devolverLikes($db,$idPhoto){
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as Likes FROM estatus where estatus = ? and idPhoto = ?";
  $consulta = $db->prepare($sql);
  $consulta->execute(array('L',$idPhoto));
  return $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function devolverDislikes($db,$idPhoto){
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as Dislikes FROM estatus where estatus = ? and idPhoto = ?";
  $consulta = $db->prepare($sql);
  $consulta->execute(array('D',$idPhoto));
  return $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function imgRandom($db,$anterior){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos where urlPath != ? order by rand() LIMIT 1";
  $consulta = $db->prepare($sql);
  $consulta->execute(array($anterior));
  return $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function construirComentario($db,$idPhoto){
  $sql = "SELECT * from comentarios where idPhoto = ?";
  $comentarios = $db->prepare($sql);
  $comentarios->execute(array($idPhoto));  

  $comentar="";
  while($fila=$comentarios->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $comentar.="
    <div class='comment'>
      <a>".$fila['username'].": </a><span>".$fila['comentario']."</span>
    </div>";
  }
  return $comentar;
}

function construirHashtags($db,$idPhoto){

  $sql = "SELECT valueHashtag AS hash from hashtagsPub where idPhoto = ?";
  $hashtag = $db->prepare($sql);
  $hashtag->execute(array($idPhoto));

  $hashtags="";
 
  while($fila=$hashtag->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $hashtags.= "<a href='#'>".$fila['hash']."</a>";
  }

  return $hashtags;
}
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código de la función `devolverRating()`, ahí es donde debe estar el error.

Comment: ya esta, he editado la pregunta con el código

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Hablas sobre la base de datos, pero en tu código no se ve ninguna consulta a la BD. Luego, si el problema está en `devolverRating()` haz un debug de esa función. Por ejemplo, en ella yo no entiendo el sentido del `if` , no hay un `else` para él y el código sigue su curso, entonces, ¿para qué es ese `if`?

Comment: Bueno las otras funciones que hacen una consulta de bd no me dan error. Me da error justo en esta función. Basicamente lo que hace la función es que si la $r tiene un 4, hara un for que ira pintando estrellas rellenas hasta 4 y la última la pintara vacia. Y si $r vale 0 entonces pintara estrellas solo vacias. No se si me explico.

Comment: Igualmente, la función la he probado varias veces y funciona correctamente, no se a que se debería.

Comment: Tal vez puede ser un problema de optimización. ¿Cada función que recibe `$db` como parámetro realiza una consulta a base de datos? Seguramente hay formas de mejorarlo, pero debes editar la pregunta para agregar las consultas y la estructura de las tablas.

Comment: si, cada función que le pasa $db significa una petición a la base de datos

Comment: he editado la pregunta otra vez con las funciones y lo que hacen cada una

Comment: Yo no logro entender el asunto. ¿Tú haces una petición Ajax para llamar a cada función?

Comment: No, cuento con un slider del cual cada vez que da click muestra una imagen random, de la cual cada imagen tiene una descripción, numero de likes y dislikes, hashtags... En vez de hacerlo por método post normal y cargar la página, he querido hacerlo por ajax sin recargar la página, de esa manera es dinámico. No se si me he explicado

Answer (score 0):

el problema no está en la función devolverRating, que funciona perfectamente si los valores que les pasas ($likes, $dislikes) tienen como contenido un número.
El problema lo tienes en las funciones devolverlikes y devolverdislikes, puesto que el retorno de los datos lo haces de la siguiente forma.

```
return $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

De esta forma lo que devuelves es un array asociativo con el resultado del Count, en lugar de un número puro y duro. Deberías devolver simplemente ese número, para que cuando ejecutes la función devolverRating no se estrelle en el if al sumar arrays en lugar de números. Simplemente devuelve la consulta directamente.

```
return $consulta;
```

o mejor todavía...

```
return intVal($consulta);
```

Comment: Pero tanto cambia el hecho de return $consulta; y return $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 ?

Comment: Pues claro que cambia, no es lo mismo sumar 2+3 que Array ( [0] => 2 ) + Array ( [0] => 3 ), prueba a hacer la modificación a ver si te funciona.

Comment: voy a probar, pero al hacer un return a la variable $likes, esta variable contendra ya el valor no tengo que acceder con ella como $likes['Likes'] ?

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo fallo, de hecho tengo comentado el rating, pero solo con cambiar el return a return $consulta o return intVal($consulta) el ajax deja de responder no entiendo porque.

Comment: Te has contestado tu mismo, si lo dejas como estaba y recibes un array, lo que le estás pasando a devolverRating sigue siendo un array, pero en devolverRating, lo tratas como una variable normal, por eso no funciona.

Comment: He hecho como me dices, pero me sigue petando a la hora de devolver el dato y me marca que ya es un int, no entiendo a que se debe

Comment: Haz un var_dump o print_r de $Dislikes y $Likes antes de llamar a devolverRating y pon por aquí el resultado, eso nos sacará de dudas.

Comment: Me ha saltado este error "Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int"

Comment: Creo que lo he solucionado, lo que he hecho ha sido   ```$row=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $count = $row["Dislikes"];
  return $count;```

Comment: Me alegro, al final lo que has hecho es convertir el array que te devuelve la consulta en una variable normal y devolverla así para que la función devolverRating no se estrelle con un array. Es lo mismo que quería hacerte entender. Perfecto entonces!!!